# Better to deduplicate inside VHDX on client or outside VHDX on host?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, deduplication, vhdx

I have a 16TB array that I'm hosting in a virtual environment. It contains video and photos from our marketing department. The data resides on the Hyper-V host itself as a VHDX file on a 8-drive SATA array. Our file server is virtualized and running Server 2012 R2.
Would best practices be to deduplicate the data from within the file server client, or would it be better to deduplicate the VHDX file on the host? Both?

Comment: Hi. I would mark as a dupe, as it's a real dupe, but for the answer in the dupe check the updated link, as I didn't found any other information for that issue either.